# How to apply diffForHumans on custom timestamp expire_at?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I saw many problems related to this,when I used diffForHumans() in controller, I was getting error "A two digit month could not be found".Please guide me how to use this.

This is my controller logic:

```
$expiredate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($currentdate. '+ 30 days'));
$expire_at = Carbon::parse($expiredate); 
$data = Subscription::where('email','=',$userEmail)->get();
$data[0]->expire_at=$expire_at;
$data[0]->save();
```

This is my view:

```
<td>{{$Data1->expire_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
```

Currently with this logic I'm getting expire_at like this  "2018-07-25 05:25:09" and I want it to like "30 days from now" or like "30 days left" something.

Answer (score 1):

> It can be or not?

```
$expiredate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($currentdate. '+ 30 days'));
//$expire_at = Carbon::parse($expiredate);

$data=Subscription::where('email','=',$userEmail)->first();
$data->expire_at = $expiredate;
$data->save();

In view:

//{{$Data1->expire_at}}
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($Data1->expire_at)->diffForHumans() }}
```

Comment: Possible but I dont want formate like "2018-04-26 10:52:21"...I want it like " 1month from now" or "1 month left".
I just want to show diffForHumans() in my view...how it will possible?

Comment: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($Data1->expire_at)->diffForHumans() }} have you tried this?

Comment: "Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string" I'm getting this error after using this

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Carbon.html are you using Carbon class in your controller or project.